# How do I use the Rails Vacuum Gem and get XML from the response

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to fool around with the [Vacuum gem](https://github.com/hakanensari/vacuum), but I have some issues with the example. When I run the code as described on the frontpage:

```
req = Vacuum.new

req.configure key:    'foo',
              secret: 'secret',
              tag:    'biz-val'

params = { 'Operation'   => 'ItemSearch',
           'SearchIndex' => 'Books',
           'Keywords'    => 'Architecture' }

res = req.get query: params # XPath is your friend.
```

I am having issues getting the XML from the response. I can see that the object type is `Excon::Response` and actually contains data, but how do I retrieve the XML it contains?

I have tried with both res.to_xml and res.xml, and even loading it into Nokogiri, but with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out. XML was saved in the object Body in the response.